# How can I create an npm package where submodules can be imported directly

Tags: node.js, npm, lodash, node-modules, npm-package

How can I create an npm package where submodules can be imported directly, such as with
`const logger = require('server-package-poc/logger')?`
I want the same functionality as in the lodash or crypto-js packages

```
// server-package-poc/index.ts
import greeter from "./greeter";
import logger from "./logger";

export { greeter, logger };
```

[image]

how can i access logger/greeter without /dist?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a folder called `submodule`
2. Add `index.js` in the `submodule`

Comment: These folders are already there. 
updated ^

Comment: The error on the screenshot is caused by mismatch `"` and `'`

Comment: The issue is not with that i don't want to access something from /dist. Its should be like 
`const logger = require("server-package-poc/logger");`
updated ^

Comment: You compiled your typescript into javascript to the dist folder

Comment: Otherwise what should i do?